# Telerik raddatepicker refusing to show

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using telerik radate picker but its refusing to show im using the adminlte theme but its still not refusing to show

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdDateOfBirth"
                       Style="vertical-align: middle;"
                       MinDate="2006-02-01"
                       runat="server"
                       MaxDate="2099-12-16"
                       Culture="en-US"
                       FocusedDate="2006-02-01"
                       Width="136px"
                       AutoPostBack="True"
                       SelectedDate="2015-11-12" S
                       kin="Bootstrap">
    <DateInput ID="DateInput3"
               runat="server"
               DateFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy"
               Height="20px"
               AutoPostBack="True"
               DisplayText="12-Nov-2015"
               SelectedDate="2015-11-12"
               value="12-Nov-2015">
        <EmptyMessageStyle Resize="None"></EmptyMessageStyle>
        <HovredStyle Resize="None">
            </HoveredStyle>
            <EnabledStyle Resize="None"></EnabledStyle>
    </DateInput>
    <Calendar ID="Calendar3"
              runat="server"
              UseRowHeadersAsSelectors="False"
              UseColumnHeadersAsSelectors="False"
              ViewSelectorText="x"
              EnableKeyboardNavigation="True"
              Skin="Bootstrap"></Calendar>
    <DatePopupButton ImageUrl=""
                     HoverImageUrl="">
    </DatePopupButton>
```

I also made sure I added telerik radscript manager but still no dice

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1"
                          runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"
                             Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"
                             Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"
                             Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
    </Scripts>
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

Comment: `S kin="Bootstrap">` is it typing mistake or you have written it in code too?

Comment: indeed.. it's hard to tell whether the error is typo or not.. was attempting to edit the question.. but.. blah..

Comment: `HovredStyle` is also incorrect... again, is this a question typo.. or an actual issue in your code?

Comment: also, you stated you're using adminlte theme, but I'm see your skin reference Bootstrap.. is correct?

Comment: is seems you've put the `Calender` control within the `RadDatePicker` control. that is probably not correct..

Comment: @BrettCaswell i also thought to edit it... but then shacked my head.

kymberly see your code check your typing mistakes, if error still persists then post it with proper edit

Comment: well.. it needs to be edited.. there's an entire section of code snippet invisible on it..

Comment: that code was autogen by telerik so

Comment: i dont no what happend to the edit these are mistakes by the editor not the code

Comment: sorry but blah is not  helpful and also very hurtfull to people who cant spell well I will  re edit when I can be bothere !